# Solubility of ortho- and para-nitrophenol in benzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, solubility, aromatic-compounds, hydrogen-bond

Which one between *o*-nitrophenol and *p*-nitrophenol is more soluble in benzene? And what is the reason? If the solvent had been polar, hydrogen bonding would have provided a lot of explanation, but what about non polar solvents?

Comment: Same thing$ $...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The nitrophenols have completely different physical behavior based on the position of nitro group:

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\hline
\text{Compound}  & \text{Melting point} & \text{Boiling point} & \text{Water solubility at } \pu{25 ^\circ C}\\
\hline
\text{2-Nitrophenol}  & \pu{43-45 ^\circ C} & \pu{215 ^\circ C}  & \pu{2 g/L} \\
\text{3-Nitrophenol}  & \pu{89-95 ^\circ C} & \pu{278 ^\circ C}  & \pu{13.5 g/L} \\
\text{4-Nitrophenol}  & \pu{113-114 ^\circ C} & \pu{279 ^\circ C}  & \pu{16 g/L} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

This different behavior is due to having intramolecular hydrogen bonding:

[image: Nitrophenols]

Due to these intramolecular H-bonding on 2-nitrophenol, its $\ce{OH}$ group is not readily available to form a hydrogen bond with solvent water. Hence 2-nitrophenol is sparingly soluble in water while 3- and 4-nitrophenol are soluble due to intermolecular H-bonding with water.

Similarly, because 3- and 4-nitrophenols contains much more intermolecular H-bonding than that of 2-nitrophenol, they have large difference in boiling and melting points than that of 2-nitrophenol (need extra energy to break intermolecular H-bonding; The intramolecular H-bonding increases the volatile nature of the molecule comparatively with their isomeric siblings that cannot have intramolecular H-bonding, thus effecting the relevant boiling points).

The intramolecular H-bonding effects oppositely in the solubility in nonpolar solvents such as benzene. Compounds involved in intramolecular H-bonding (kind of chelation) become non-polar (not many interaction forces intermolecularly). As a consequent, these compounds are soluble in nonpolar solvents (oposite to only sparingly soluble in water) whereas their meta and para isomers are less soluble in non-polar solvents but more soluble in water due to intermolecular H-bonding (such as water).

Comment: Good answer but your answer tells that Ortho nitrophenol will be more soluble than para and meta and it contradicts with the first answer!?

Comment: Not really. For example, check percent composition at $\pu{40 ^\circ C}$ at all three isomers in @Aniruddha Deb answer. That was about 90% for 2-nitrophenol. To get the same composition, you need to increase the temperature to about  $\pu{90 ^\circ C}$ for 3-nitrophenol and  $\pu{105 ^\circ C}$ for 4-nitro-isomer. Aniruddha Deb's interpretation is incorrect.

Answer (score 13):

It turns out that the opposite of what happens in polar solvents takes place when a non-polar solvent is used. At the same temperature, *o*-nitrophenol is **more soluble** in benzene than it's *m* and *p* isomers.

Sidgwick *et al.*<sup>1</sup> did a study of this and obtained the following results. (Note that the solvent they used was toluene and not benzene, but they are similar enough that the same principles would apply.)

> [image: solubility of nitrophenols in toluene]

**EDIT**: The original version of this answer wrongly interpreted the graph and stated that *o*-nitrophenol would be less soluble in benzene than the other isomers. That was an error on my part. Thank you to Mathew Mahindaratne for pointing it out!

**References**:

1. Nevil Vincent Sidgwick, William James Spurrell, Thomas Ellis Davies, “CXXXII.—The Solubility of the Nitrophenols and Other Isomeric Disubstitution Products of Benzene,” *J. Chem. Soc., Trans.* **1915**, *107*, 1202–1213. doi:[10.1039/CT9150701202](https://doi.org/10.1039/CT9150701202).

Comment: Good reply. But yours and 2nd one contradict each other?!

Comment: @Aniruddha Deb: Please see my comment to OP's question under y answer. According to chart, solubility should be higher for 2-nitrophenol than that of other two at all temperatures. Accordingly, would you correct your answer.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne I edited the answer. Thank you for pointing it out :)